# Send a message for many Genservers to act at the same time and know they have all acted?

Tags: elixir

I've created many GenServers and send messages to them one at a time using PIDs. But, I want them all to act at roughly the same time on a single "turn" in a game. How can I: (1) broadcast a "go!" message to them (2) know that they have all finished acting (i.e. turn is over)?

Comment: *How can I: (1) broadcast a "go!" message to them (2) know that they have all finished acting (i.e. turn is over)?*  What if a GenServer receives the "go" message, then immediately crashes?  You won't know whether the GenServer is still doing some work or it crashed--unless you link/monitor the GenServer process.  Then, what do you want to do if a GenServer crashes?  Things can get pretty complicated--that's why there's OTP.

Comment: ...The programmers who came up with OTP did all the hard work in these complex scenarios, and you can leverage their hard work by using OTP. If you want to restart a crashed GenServer and have it complete its work, then you can use an OTP Supervisor.  It's not a bad exercise to try to do things by hand to get exposed to the complexity, though.  With each iteration of your solution, someone can point out the edge cases and flaws that you don't address.

Comment: @7stud, I appreciate this advice and will work with an OTP Supervisor. Right now I'm more concerned with timing than with crashing.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could achieve what you want would be to `cast` out all of the `go` messages, and then reply asynchronously:

```
defmodule TurnTracker do
  use GenServer

  def init(pids) do
    state = %{
      pids: pids,
      ongoing_requests: MapSet.new()
    }
    {:ok, state}
  end

  # This will send out your go message to all genservers
  def handle_call(:broadcast, _from, state) do

    Enum.each(state.pids, fn pid ->
      GenServer.cast(pid, {:go, self()})
    end)

    # The ongoing_requests is just a collection of all of the pids for the Player processes.  One-by-one they will be removed using the handle_cast underneath here.
    updated_state = Map.put(state, :ongoing_requests, MapSet.new(state.pids))

    {:reply, :ok, updated_state}
  end

  # When one of the genservers is done its turn, it will send a message to here
  def handle_cast({:completed_turn, pid}, state) do

    # Remove the pid from the set, eventually we will remove them all
    ongoing_requests = MapSet.delete(state.ongoing_requests, pid)
    updated_state = Map.put(state, :ongoing_requests, ongoing_requests)

    # Check to see if that was the last one, if it was, all of the Players are done their turns
    if MapSet.size(ongoing_requests) == 0 do
      # All of your GenServers are done
    else
      # One or more are not done yet
    end

    {:noreply, updated_state}
  end
end


# You will have a bunch of these
defmodule Player do
  use GenServer

  def handle_cast({:go, turn_tracker_pid}, state) do
    # Your turn logic here

    # Tell the TurnTracker that we are done
    GenServer.cast(turn_tracker_pid, {:completed_turn, self()})

    {:noreply, state}
  end
end
```

There isn't really a way to guarantee that your GenServers will act at the same time because when you send a message you are just putting a message in their mailboxes and there could be other messages ahead of yours.

If the turns take more than 5 seconds (the default timeout for the `Genserver.call`) then the `:broadcast` will timeout here.

Comment: Thanks @Tyler. I thought there may be a special function for broadcasting to multiple PIDs. Iterating through a collection is a familiar solution. In your example, the Player does not register with the TurnTracker, so I don't understand how TurnTracker generates its list of PIDs at the start of every turn.

Comment: I added the list of `pids` to the `init` of the TurnTracker, I figured you could pass them in on startup (so, start all of the Players first).

Answer (score 0):

For the simplest solution I'd make the `GenServer` message synchronous (by using `call` instead of `cast` to send the message) and start a `Task` per server to wait for the result (in order not to block the original calling process and be able to trigger many messages at the same time). Basically something like this:

```
servers
|> Enum.map(fn server -> Task.async(fn -> GenServer.call(server, :go) end) end)
|> Enum.map(&Task.await/1)
```

Note that `Task.await` has a default timeout, so if your turns take really long you might want to increase that.